# ios: NSAttributedString allocation bug

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nsattributedstring

I have a view which allocates a UILabel and sets the attributed string using NSAttributedString from HTML string. I get the crash during initialising the NSAttributedString. Following is the stack trace of the error:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ???                            0x15e9d6c0 
1  QuartzCore                     0x2d967993 CA::Display::DisplayLink::get_link(CA::Display::Display*, __CFRunLoop*, X::List<__CFString const*> const*) + 254
2  QuartzCore                     0x2d967723 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::update_link(__CFRunLoop*) + 162
3  QuartzCore                     0x2d98a823 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 170
4  QuartzCore                     0x2d98a643 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 366
5  IOMobileFramebuffer            0x3288dc07 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 90
6  IOKit                          0x2b827001 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
7  CoreFoundation                 0x2a86324d __CFMachPortPerform + 132
8  CoreFoundation                 0x2a8737cb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
9  CoreFoundation                 0x2a873767 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
10 CoreFoundation                 0x2a871d69 __CFRunLoopRun + 1608
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2a7be201 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2a7be013 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
13 UIFoundation                   0x3629bb7f -[NSHTMLReader _loadUsingWebKit] + 1950
14 UIFoundation                   0x3629ce31 -[NSHTMLReader attributedString] + 24
15 UIFoundation                   0x36244445 _NSReadAttributedStringFromURLOrData + 5648
16 UIFoundation                   0x36242dad -[NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringUIFoundationAdditions) initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:] + 116
17 PageViewScrollView             0x0002ff54 @!objc ext.UIKit.ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString.init (ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString.Type)(data : ObjectiveC.NSData, options : Swift.Optional<Swift.Dictionary<ObjectiveC.NSObject, Swift.AnyObject>>, documentAttributes : Swift.AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.NSDictionary>>, error : Swift.AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.NSError>>) -> Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString> (HTMLTextView.swift)
18 PageViewScrollView             0x00029da4 ext.UIKit.ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString.init (ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString.Type)(data : ObjectiveC.NSData, options : Swift.Optional<Swift.Dictionary<ObjectiveC.NSObject, Swift.AnyObject>>, documentAttributes : Swift.AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.NSDictionary>>, error : Swift.AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.NSError>>) -> Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString> (HTMLTextView.swift)
19 PageViewScrollView             0x00026fd4 PageViewScrollView.HTMLTextView.init (PageViewScrollView.HTMLTextView.Type)(frame : C.CGRect) -> PageViewScrollView.HTMLTextView (HTMLTextView.swift:33)
20 PageViewScrollView             0x000286ac PageViewScrollView.HTMLTextView.__allocating_init (PageViewScrollView.HTMLTextView.Type)(frame : C.CGRect) -> PageViewScrollView.HTMLTextView (HTMLTextView.swift)
21 PageViewScrollView             0x0003fe4c PageViewScrollView.ViewController.getView (PageViewScrollView.ViewController)(Swift.Int) -> Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.UIView> (ViewController.swift:149)
22 PageViewScrollView             0x0003c7f8 PageViewScrollView.ViewController.scrollViewDidScroll (PageViewScrollView.ViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIScrollView) -> () (ViewController.swift:86)
23 PageViewScrollView             0x0003f5fc @objc PageViewScrollView.ViewController.scrollViewDidScroll (PageViewScrollView.ViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIScrollView) -> () (ViewController.swift)
24 UIKit                          0x2e1dc115 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 64
25 UIKit                          0x2df451d5 -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 632
26 UIKit                          0x2e0be771 -[UIScrollView _smoothScrollWithUpdateTime:] + 3120
27 QuartzCore                     0x2d98a7db CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 98
28 QuartzCore                     0x2d98a643 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 366
29 IOMobileFramebuffer            0x3288dc07 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 90
30 IOKit                          0x2b827001 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
31 CoreFoundation                 0x2a86324d __CFMachPortPerform + 132
32 CoreFoundation                 0x2a8737cb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
33 CoreFoundation                 0x2a873767 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
34 CoreFoundation                 0x2a871d69 __CFRunLoopRun + 1608
35 CoreFoundation                 0x2a7be201 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
36 CoreFoundation                 0x2a7be013 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
37 GraphicsServices               0x3228f201 GSEventRunModal + 136
38 UIKit                          0x2df8aa09 UIApplicationMain + 1440
39 PageViewScrollView             0x000448f4 main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
40 libdyld.dylib                  0x397a3aaf start + 2
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/shahankit/PageViewScrollView) to the source code of app where I've used this function. Basically it's a view pager using UIScrollView where views are added and removed as the user so as to keep minimal number of total view in memory. During initialisation of new views containing UILabel with NSAttributedString the above occurs. While scrolling from one view to other new view are created and older are removed from scrollView

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the bug. The problem was that scrollViewDidScroll callbacks are sent on background thread. And I was performing UI updates on background which was causing the problem. Executing the code on main thread using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block` solved the issue.